# My Paste function isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the entry forms I select from the master list to a different worksheet. The idea is that it goes down a condensed list of names without details. Looks at what I have selected. Copies the selected entry form and pastes it in a new place to generate a list that only contains the entry forms I need. I can't tell if the loop is working properly because the paste function at the end isn't working.

```
   Sub BidList()


'Sets unique terms used throught this code
  Dim wQuick As Worksheet, wMaster As Worksheet
  Dim BlankFound As Boolean
  Dim x As Long, n As Long, y As Long
  Dim firstrow As Long, pasterow As Long, lastrow As Long, PasteCell As String, MyRange As String

 'Turns off Screen updating to save memory
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Store an initial value for "x" effectively starting the macro at C4 after the +1 in the next step
   x = 3
   n = 0
   y = 0

  Set wQuick = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quick Reference")
  Set wMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
  BlankFound = False

'Loop until x equals 600
  Do While BlankFound = False
    x = x + 1
    n = n + 1
    If Trim(wQuick.Cells(x, "B").Value) = "" Then Exit Do




'If there is a 1 in the Boolean column then ...
    If Trim(wQuick.Cells(x, "C").Value) = "1" Then

 'Move the y value so that the template is pasted in the appropriate place
    y = y + 1


'Copy the appropriate form from wMaster
    firstrow = (n * 9) + 18
    lastrow = (n * 9) + 27

    Let MyRange = "A" & firstrow & ":" & "K" & lastrow

    wMaster.Range(MyRange).Copy

'Select the next place for the form to be pasted on wQuick

    pasterow = (y * 9) - 5

     Let PasteCell = "F" & "," & pasterow
     wQuick.Cells(PasteCell).Paste


    End If



  Loop


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of those `Let` btw.

Comment: Better to work with `Range` objects, not their addresses, but that line could be `wQuick.Range("F" & pasteRow).Paste`. `Cells` needs two arguments here, not one string argument with a comma in it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid copy-paste in Excel, better use a for-loop like the following:

```
# keep track of MyRange.Row and MyRange.Column
For Each cell in wMaster.Range(MyRange):
  wQuick.Cells(<Starting point>).Offset(<take the cell coordinates, based on MyRange.Row and/or MyRange.Column>).Value = cell.Value
Next
```

Comment: `Please avoid copy-paste in Excel` Are you saying this for this particular scenario or for in general?

Comment: I couldn't get that method to work with what i was trying to do because i need it to paste the entry forms to the next available space and my entry forms are 9 rows high but i did get it working. Unfortunately it still uses copy and paste. I appreciate you taking the time to help.